# Sorting struct from binary file in C

Tags: c, struct

So i have a struct like this one:

```
typedef struct caravana{
char matricula[50];
char marca[50];
char modelo[50];
int ano;
char tipo[50];
int nPessoas;
float areaConv;
float precoDia;
char obs[50];
}CR;
```

I'm storing the input data on the structure on a binary file. Now i have to use that data and sort it by decreasing order using the variable precoDia. Does anybody have any idea on how to do it?

Comment: With a sorting algorithm. Like quicksort https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329725/how-does-krs-qsort-work

Comment: Or use [`qsort()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3p.html).